# Repair a broken git repo - how to have a fresh start

Tags: git, repository

I am somewhat of a newbie with git and was frustrated with how my repo was working.. or in this case not working.. so I deleted it off of git hub, deleted the git folder on the project and was planning to start fresh.

Now when i try and set up a fresh repo I am getting a lot of messages like :

```
warning: You appear to be on a branch yet to be born.
warning. Forcing checkout of HEAD
```

when I try and run the first commit I see :

```
error: invalid object 8bcb4b5fd612e3ad55fb07e4bed087c55afd0861
fatal: git-write-tree: error building trees
```

I ran git fsck and see that I am missing a bunch of blobs.

How can I just wipe the slate clean and try again?

Comment: but you have a backup of the previous repository, right?

Comment: no.. but i dont care about this particular one.. i just want to start the repo from this point forward..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok,

1. have backups
2. git clean -dfx .
3. mv .git **/tmp/**_git.backup
4. git init
5. git add .
6. git commit -m 'restart repo after rescue operation'

Note the `clean` step that prevents a lot of previously untracked stuff from being added to the new repo. A good .gitignore goes a long way to prevent effects like that.

If you want, you can manually migrate some/all of the old configuration, like

```
 vim -d _git.backup/config .git/config
```

(or simply copy it)

I'll not go into obvious details about impact on potential remote clones/branches :)

There are ways to reconcile things like that, but for now, this seems to answer your question.

Comment: i was able to do a first commit.. but then on my next commit I got this:  
  from f41e77d09f58505d844256092f00e32ac5d944f3
  to   9d82c78f89021f60c7e9301646e5da49d75f58d5
Generating pack...
Done counting 13 objects.
Result has 10 objects.
error: unable to find 0111a2bb274758f23582dee28521504f48220768
fatal: unable to get type of object 0111a2bb274758f23582dee28521504f48220768
error: pack-objects died with strange error
unpack eof before pack header was fully read
ng refs/heads/master n/a (unpacker error)

Comment: Please explain precisely which steps you have followed and in what order. The message 'from <hash> to <hash>' does not seem at all to come from git commit. So, perhaps you have kept/copied back a hook. Perhaps, you have done something different alltogether ...

Comment: well.. i skipped 1.. because i already deleted eveyrthing.  the syntax git clean -dfx does not work for me so i separated out those flags.. git clean -d -f -x.  Then it allowed me to commit the first time.  I then made some changes to a file and tried to commit that and that is when I am getting the error.  There is one line before the <hash> which is updating 'refs/heads/master'.  I do not understand why it is still trying to find that hash as I thought I had wiped everything to start over..

Comment: So let me get this straight. You skipped steps 3. 4. and 5.?

Comment: no sorry .. i did all of those too.. so successful first commit.. but then any following commits not work

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. Check A. I recommend _not_ copying over anything from an old/other .git directory for checks B. unset GIT_DIR, GIT_WORK_TREE and GIT_INDEX variables C. Also, you might want to make sure that you're not accidentally mixing bare/non-bare repositories in place (e.g. check the output of find -name refs after step 3, it should not return anything git-related at that point). Also note (bolded) I made my step 3 stronger