# error: remote unpack failed: eof before pack header was fully read

Tags: git

Before that I got a problem `error: object file is empty` cause my laptop sunddenly turn off. I was fixed with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12371337/8706997). My local repo was fixed and I try to pull and push to remote master. But I have a problem like this

```sh
$ git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 26, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (22/22), done.
fatal: unable to read c779d43453f63d871ba2a079b79f04558d9b0920
error: remote unpack failed: eof before pack header was fully read
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:xxxx/xxxx.git'
```

How to fix my remote repo? I can't push my new commit cause broken remote repo

How to fix `unable to read c779d43453f63d871ba2a079b79f04558d9b0920` on remote repo?

Comment: Would https://stackoverflow.com/a/5860180/6309 help?

Comment: i was fixed on my file with `git hash-object -w pages/promo.vue`

Answer (score 21):

I'm on a shared hosting and I had the same problem while trying to push master for the first time.

But this did the trick:

```
git config --global pack.windowMemory "100m"
git config --global pack.packSizeLimit "100m"
git config --global pack.threads "1"
```

Comment: Worked for me. Any idea what might cause this to become needed? Is it an indication that there is a large file somewhere in the repo? (If so I need to remove it before it causes bigger problems)

Comment: I think it's not enough memory when compressing large files.

Comment: This did the trick. Def. because of large file sizes.

Comment: This one did the trick for me as well. On shared hosting.

Answer (score 13):

I had this occur for me in a number of repos, I eventually traced it back to the repos being stored inside of my Dropbox and "selective sync" being applied. As a result the `.git` folder wasn't fully available locally.

Going into the folder in finder and selecting *selective sync* > *local* fixed it.

The parent folder was marked to be synced, but Dropbox seems to assume that hidden folders probably aren't important.

Comment: I can attest this does happen, actually. Grr, Dropbox.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar error with git 2.19.0 which was fixed by updating to git 2.20.1. I believe in my case git crashed while trying to compress a specific object (it only got to "Compressing objects: 31%") and then the server returned that error due to the sending process having crashed.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Updating git fixed the issue for me as well, but it was 2.20.1 to 2.21.0 for me. Which leads me to believe that it is not a fix in the update, but rather a setting that is reset or a cache cleared during the update process.

Comment: Same for me. Upgraded from Git Scm 2.19 to 2.21 and then everything work like a charm !

Answer (score 9):

It happened for me on macOS Big Sur and upgrading my git version fixed it. Initial version was 2.23.0, upgraded to git version 2.29.2.

Answer (score 7):

```sh
git fsck
```

did the trick and solved it for me

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem yesterday, my laptop shut down unexpectedly. So I had to re-create git.

First of all, remove the **.git** folder from your directory.

```
rm -rf .git
```

Then create renew git.

```
git init
```

All the tracking will become new, so you have to commit all the new changes and add your remote repository

```
git remote add origin <repo URL>
```

If for example, you were on the "development" branch. Go ahead create a development branch

```
git branch development && git checkout development
```

Now after switching to the development branch, pull from the remote branch.

```
git pull origin development --allow-unrelated-histories
```

You may face conflicts, resolve them and you are good to go.

Comment: the real MVP.. !! worked like a charm and even understood what was happening

Answer (score 4):

Your local repository *isn't* fixed, because this message:

> ```
> fatal: unable to read c779d43453f63d871ba2a079b79f04558d9b0920
> ```

came from your own Git, while it was trying to package data to send to the remote.  (The way to know this is that it's not prefixed by `remote:`.)  The remaining errors:

> ```
> error: remote unpack failed: eof before pack header was fully read
> error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:xxxx/xxxx.git'
> ```

are consequences of this.

This problem has not affected the *other* repository in any way, so you can make a new clone of the other repository and do whatever you can to extract useful data from your not-quite-fixed repository to add to the new (good) clone.

Comment: i was fixed on my file with `git hash-object -w pages/promo.vue`.

Answer (score 2):

It can be due to comparatively large size/number of files in the commit. When tried with zipping, it worked for me

Comment: How do you try with zipping? Is there an extra argument or config you can add to `git push` to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Another way this error can occur is when working with Git **submodules** and trying to push to the remote (even with `--force`) **when the local repository has not pulled yet the newer references** from the remote.

The solution for this use case is to update the submodule(s) like so:

```bash
git submodule update --remote
```

In this case, performing `git fsck` will also result in an error (commit hash cut off for brevity):

```bash
$ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (3628/3628), done.
error: refs/remotes/origin/some/branch: invalid reflog entry 1c857
```